# Javascript to edit json file

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I've got a .json file that looks like this:

```
[
    [
        1513814400000,
        0.8433
    ]
]
```

Now, my question is this: I need to modify every 2nd value in this file, i.e:

```
0.8433 -> 8.433
```

I already wrote a javascript that loads the file using jQuery, however I'm not sure how I can go through the file and edit these values. The manipulation is always the same, for example:

```
new value = old value * 10
```

Any tips on how I could do this?

Comment: `array[0][0]*10`  ??

Comment: Can do this with multiple different loop approaches. A `for` loop, `Array#forEach`, `Array#map` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say:

```
var array = [[1,2], [2,3],....[n,m]];
```

Then you can do:

```
array = array.map(element => {
  if(element[1]) element[1] = element[1] * 10;
  return element;
});
```

The result will be:

```
array = [[1,20], [2,30],....[n,m*10]];
```